# How to show an image on the camera of an android smartphone? Without being android emulated for pc

Tags: android, image, mobile, camera, emulation

I was able to play an image or video to an android device's camera using splitcam + bluestacks. However, I would like to do the same on a native android smartphone but I can't imagine how to do it or if it's possible, as I'm not a mobile developer yet. I'll leave an example image of how it worked in bluestacks. [imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMNyU.jpg)